# Mangled packets from libnetfilter_queue do not reach destination

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, ipv4, netfilter

I'm trying to use libnetfilter_queue to add custom options to the IP headers of certain packets.

As a test, I've tried modifying the sample program from the libnetfilter_queue documentation ([nf-queue.c](https://git.netfilter.org/libnetfilter_queue/tree/examples/nf-queue.c)) to change the TTL value in the header. The packets appear in Wireshark with the modified contents, but they don't seem to actually reach the destination.

This is the modified callback function from the libnetfilter_queue example. It changes the TTL value from the default 64 to 88.

```c
static int queue_cb(const struct nlmsghdr *nlh, void *data)
{
    struct nfqnl_msg_packet_hdr *ph = NULL;
    struct nlattr *attr[NFQA_MAX+1] = {};
    uint32_t id = 0, skbinfo;
    int queue_num;
    struct nfgenmsg *nfg;

    uint16_t plen;
    void *payload;
    struct pkt_buff *pktb;
    uint8_t new_ttl = 88;

    char buf[MNL_SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE];
    struct nlmsghdr *nlh_verdict;
    struct nlattr *nest;

    /* Parse netlink message received from the kernel, the array of
     * attributes is set up to store metadata and the actual packet.
     */
    if (nfq_nlmsg_parse(nlh, attr) < 0) {
        perror("problems parsing");
        return MNL_CB_ERROR;
    }

    nfg = mnl_nlmsg_get_payload(nlh);

    if (attr[NFQA_PACKET_HDR] == NULL) {
        fputs("metaheader not set\n", stderr);
        return MNL_CB_ERROR;
    }

    /* Access packet metadata, which provides unique packet ID, hook number
     * and ethertype. See struct nfqnl_msg_packet_hdr for details.
     */
    ph = mnl_attr_get_payload(attr[NFQA_PACKET_HDR]);
    id = ntohl(ph->packet_id);
    queue_num = ntohs(nfg->res_id);

    /* Access actual packet data length. */
    plen = mnl_attr_get_payload_len(attr[NFQA_PAYLOAD]);

    /* Access actual packet data */
    payload = mnl_attr_get_payload(attr[NFQA_PAYLOAD]);

    /* Copy to packet buffer with extra space for mangling */
    pktb = pktb_alloc(AF_INET, payload, plen, 255);

    /* Change TTL */
    nfq_ip_mangle(
        pktb,
        0,
        offsetof(struct iphdr, ttl),
        sizeof(((struct iphdr *)0)->ttl),
        &new_ttl,
        sizeof(new_ttl)
    );

    /* Accept mangled packet */
    nlh_verdict = nfq_nlmsg_put(buf, NFQNL_MSG_VERDICT, ntohs(nfg->res_id));
    if (pktb_mangled(pktb)) {
        nfq_nlmsg_verdict_put_pkt(nlh_verdict, pktb_data(pktb), pktb_len(pktb));
    }
    nfq_nlmsg_verdict_put(nlh_verdict, id, NF_ACCEPT);
    if (mnl_socket_sendto(nl, nlh_verdict, nlh_verdict->nlmsg_len) < 0) {
        perror("mnl_socket_send");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return MNL_CB_OK;
}
```

To test, I've set up an nftables rule to queue packets like this:

```
nft add table inet test-table
nft add chain inet test-table test-chain '{ type filter hook output priority 0; }'
nft add rule inet test-table test-chain counter queue
```

Then I run the program and use `nc` to send UDP packets like this:

- Receiver: `nc -u -l -p 4444`
- Sender: `nc -u localhost 4444 <<< Hello`

When I do this, the modified packet appears in Wireshark, but nothing is output from the receiver's `nc` command. Wireshark displays the packet like this:

```
Frame 1: 48 bytes on wire (384 bits), 48 bytes captured (384 bits) on interface lo, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: 00:00:00_00:00:00 (00:00:00:00:00:00), Dst: 00:00:00_00:00:00 (00:00:00:00:00:00)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
    Total Length: 34
    Identification: 0xd911 (55569)
    010. .... = Flags: 0x2, Don't fragment
    ...0 0000 0000 0000 = Fragment Offset: 0
    Time to Live: 88
    Protocol: UDP (17)
    Header Checksum: 0x4bb7 [correct]
    [Header checksum status: Good]
    [Calculated Checksum: 0x4bb7]
    Source Address: 127.0.0.1
    Destination Address: 127.0.0.1
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 42078, Dst Port: 4444
    Source Port: 42078
    Destination Port: 4444
    Length: 14
    Checksum: 0xfe21 [correct] (matches partial checksum, not 0x2839, likely caused by "UDP checksum offload")
    [Checksum Status: Good]
    [Stream index: 0]
    [Timestamps]
    UDP payload (6 bytes)
Data (6 bytes)
    Data: 48656c6c6f0a
    [Length: 6]
```

When I run the same `nc` commands without the nftables rules and the program running, the packet also appears in Wireshark, and the receving `nc` command outputs `Hello` as expected.

I've also tried modifying the packet by changing the TTL to the same value (64 -> 64) using nfq_ip_mangle, but it ends up the same: the packet appears in Wireshark, but the receiving process never prints a message.

What could be the cause of this?

**UPDATE**: It seems that adding a call to `nfq_udp_mangle_ipv4` before sending the verdict makes the receiving `nc` process receive the packet and print the message. This works even if `nfq_udp_mangle_ipv4` doesn't actually change any data.

From what I can tell looking at the source code for `nfq_udp_mangle_ipv4`, it doesn't seem to be doing anything fundamentally different from what I have already. It calls `nfq_ip_mangle`, then updates the UDP checksum.

Why is the call to `nfq_udp_mangle_ipv4` necessary? What is it doing that causes the packet to go through?

Comment: There are only a few options allowed. You cannot just make up IP options and expect them to work. Read about it in RFC 791: "_What is optional is their transmission in any particular datagram, not their implementation._" In fact, the header length is 20, which means there are no options in IP as that is the minimum, and the maximum is 60 with options.

Comment: @RonMaupin I'm aware of this. I'm intending to use the experimental values reserved by RFC 4727. This will be used in a local network of VMs. The problem I've having now is that modified packets aren't going through, even without any extra options.

Comment: Even when using experimental values, every network stack in the path must understand the custom options, else the packet gets dropped. Did you write a custom IP stack for it to be able to understand the custom options? If not, it will just drop the packets with the custom options.

Comment: @RonMaupin I'm imagining that every device will have netfilter rules set up to queue packets and handle options there, just as a proof-of-concept. I'm not too familiar with netfilter, but from what I've read, it sounds like this should be possible. Using the extra call to `ǹfq_udp_mangle_ipv4`, I was able to add custom options and have the packets go through, but this is just between two VMs on the same subnet. I've not tried more complicated setups yet.